# Memory for std::queue allocated on heap or stack

Tags: c++

If I use `std::queue<ClassA> my_queue`, where is the memory allocated for the objects inside queue? If I don't use pointers for objects to be stored in queue, will it still allocate on heap?

Comment: That depends on the allocator class used in the underlying container.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how about `std::queue<int>` ?

Comment: @debonair -- Try to implement `std::queue` yourself.  You will quickly see that the only practical way to implement it is to use `new` or some sort of dynamic memory allocation to maintain the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All standard containers use an Allocator object for their memory management needs. By default, unless you provide your own, they use [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). This includes `std::deque<T>`, which is what a `std::queue<T>` uses. `std::allocator` uses the free store (the memory space used by `new` and `delete`) which is where the elements of your `std::queue` will be created.

`std::deque` and pretty much every other standard type that uses dynamically allocated objects manage that memory internally, using pointers that are not usually visible to their user. It's not because you didn't dynamically allocate an object that that object can't internally dynamically allocate memory for it's own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If no alternative `allocator` or `container` was provided: the free store because it uses a `std::deque`